# Accessing a file whom 200 other user's are trying to access at same time as well

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-2.0

I am developing a code that will be used by 200 different user's to access a single file.

What would be the best practice for me to read file which is being accessed by large number of users at same time

```
FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(FileName);
 byte[] contents = new byte[stream.Length];
 stream.Read(contents, 0, (int)stream.Length);
 stream.Close();
```

Any better way of doing it ?

Comment: You want `stream.Write` if you are uploading it. To do this concurrently you'd need to upload the file asynchronously. Will it always be the same file?

Comment: somthing goes wrong ? What goes wrong ? why upload ? Be precise.

Comment: @codebrain "Save Conflict" or Access exceptions ? I dunno I am just preparing for them..

Comment: @SamLeach changed my question title

Comment: If other users are only reading the file. There will be no problem.

Comment: Unless he's opening the file with write access by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an [overload method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/y973b725.aspx) and specify file sharing explicitly (otherwise you will encounter `UnauthorizedAccess` exceptions, when opening multiple streams):

```
var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

As long as its reading only - this should work fine.

Comment: by default it opens the file with FileShare.None, afaik.